# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDivElement])

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to pass a value to a div with id `good` in my index.html but it brings this error, `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDivElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.  in TestComponent (at App.js:49)
    in div (at App.js:28)
    in Apps (at index.js:7)`
Please what am I doing wrong

TestComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TestComponent extends Component {
componentDidMount(){
    console.log("Great");
}

render() {
   // var {test} = this.props;
    return (
        <p>
            {this.props.test}
        </p>,
            document.getElementById("good")
    );
}
}

export default TestComponent;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
 import TestComponent from "./components/TestComponent"

class Apps extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>

            <TestComponent test='doyin'/>

        </div>
    );
 }
 }

 export default Apps;
```

Index.html

```
<div id="good"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class `Component` render function shouldn't use `document.getElementById`, you need to use `ReactDOM.render` to do that

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TestComponent extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log("Great");
    }

    render() {
       // var {test} = this.props;
        return (
            <p>
                {this.props.test}
            </p>
        );
    }

}


export default TestComponent;
```

App

```
class Apps extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <TestComponent test='doyin'/>

            </div>
        );
     }

 }
 ReactDOM.render(<Apps />, document.getElementById("good"))
 export default Apps;
```

Comment: What do you mean by a class component

Comment: `TestComponent` is a React component which is written in a class pattern. Anyways, any React component should be trying to render in the document directly. The top level React component should only be rendered in DOM

Comment: ReactDOM.render(<TestComponent />, document.getElementById("good")), when i put this in testcomponent.js it doesn't work , please why

Comment: It might be because you are not passing the prop test to TestComponent in this case

Answer (score 1):

In `TestComponent.js`, inside `render` function you are trying to return two elements, `<p>` and `document.getElementById("good")`. Probably you just wanted to return `<p>`:

```
render() {
  return <p>{this.props.test}</p>;
}
```

Also, it looks like you've mistaken `React.Component.render` with `ReactDOM.render(element, container[, callback])` where the second argument of the functions is the container.